# Can I use 'like' to compare to a field in another table?

Tags: ms-access, vba, sql-like

I have two tables - `tMasks` and `tFiles`, each with one (relevant) field - `[mask]` and `[filename]` respectively.

**Sample Data and Expected Result**

For `tMasks` we have `[mask]` values of `'60moelg'`, `'adjclmrp'`, and `'arerrdoc'`.

And for `tfiles` we have `[filename]` values of `'60moelg_00'`, `'aut_cnty'`, `'exvndata00'`, and `'adjclmrp00'`.

What I need is to list all of the `[filename]` values in `tFiles` where there is no matching `[mask]` value in `tMasks`.  (So in my very limited sample here, the result would be `{'aut_cnty', 'exvndata00'}`.)

**What I Have Tried**

I was trying something along the lines of:

```
SELECT FileName
FROM tFiles
WHERE FileName not in (SELECT FileName from tFiles, tMasks  where FileName like ('mask' & '%'));
```

But that doesn't work, because

```
SELECT FileName from tFiles, tMasks WHERE FileName LIKE ('mask' & '%')
```

returns an empty set, and so the `not in` doesn't eliminate anything.

Do I need to import these columns into VBA array variants and do this 'brute force' via a for..each loop, or is this something I can do with SELECT?  It seems like it SHOULD be something I can do with SELECT, but I'm just not making the leap....

(In the 'real world', `tMasks` is less than 300 records, while `tFiles` is over 1400 records, and the ultimate point is to update (and maintain!) `tMasks` so that there are no members of `tFiles` for which there is not a matching mask in `tMasks`.  And to make it more 'interesting', I cannot use 'equals' instead of 'like', because the number of characters in the mask isn't consistent.  Some masks have 8 chars, some 7, some only 6. So I can't just compare the masks with `Left(filename, n)` using the `=` operator, because `n` would vary.)

I be stuck - Any suggestions?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the quotes from 'mask'. You don't want the STRING of mask, you want the VALUE of mask. I also changed the & to a + since my SQL Server (2012) doesn't allow the & for nvarchar data types.

```
SELECT FileName FROM tFiles 
WHERE FileName not in 
(SELECT FileName from tFiles, tMasks where FileName like (mask + '%'));
```

I set up your described scenario on my database and it returned two rows:

```
FileName
aut_cnty
exvndata00
```

Good luck!

Comment: Great - thanks for letting me know I was on the right track logic-wise, and just needed the right syntax!  which, for MS Access, for just the 'inside' select, looks like this:  "SELECT Filename FROM tFiles, tMasks  WHERE Filename like ([mask] & '*' );"  Awesome sauce.  Now it's on to create some 1100 new file masks.  But at least now I know which ones I have to create!